# How to display particular position on the MapView?

Tags: android, android-mapview

I have a position, which I need to display. The format is like:

```
lat: 59.915494, lng: 30.409456
```

Also I need to display current position of the user. The following code:

```
    MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
    mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay); 
    myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
```

doesn't center map on the current position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to adjust where the map is centered on or zoomed into you need to get the `MapController`.

```
MapController controller = mMapView.getController();
controller.animateTo(geoPoint);
// Or if you just want it to snap there
controller.setCenter(geoPoint);

controller.setZoom(5);
```

That point that you want to show you're going to need to add an `Overlay`.  Here is the [documentation](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/index.html) for that and a nice [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) on how to do it.